# Dart test coverage not showing up for lib files

Tags: dart, testing, test-coverage

How do you make coverage reports include those in under lib directory? Right now when I run tests with `dart test --coverage="coverage"`, it will only record coverage on my test files and not on the lib files. But when I change the imports declaration for my lib files relatively like:

```dart
import '../../lib/conventional.dart';
```

...instead of:

```dart
import 'package:conventional/conventional.dart';
```

...it works. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Dart version is Dart SDK version: 2.12.0 (stable)  on "linux_x64" and coverage version is 1.0.1. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/asartalo/conventional/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question on reddit and got an answer there. So after running `dart test --coverage="coverage"`, I needed to add `--packages=.packages` as in:

```sh
dart test --coverage="coverage"
format_coverage --lcov --in=coverage --out=coverage.lcov --packages=.packages --report-on=lib
```

Before, I didn't include the `--packages=.packages` option and so it was only showing coverage for the test files. The documentation for this said:

```
    --packages           path to the package spec file
```

..and didn't mention anything about the significance of that. It's been frustrating.